# how to deal with suffix and prefix in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying design a css for a dynamically generated Label. I am trying to write css for For attribute of label which can have the `anything+Textbox`. My prefix can be anything and suffix remain same. and I tried this

```
     label[for=*+"TextBox"]
    {
        color:#DD4B39;
         font-size:smaller;
    }
```

How to write css for above situation? Any help are surely appretiated.

Comment: For compatibility with older versions of IE, you should also include a style using htmlfor as well as for eg: `label[htmlfor=""]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[css Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp)***

```
label[for$="TextBox"]
    {
        color:#DD4B39;
         font-size:smaller;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

***[CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp)***

This will select every `<label>` element whose for attribute value **contains** `"TextBox"`

```
label[for*="TextBox"]{
    color:#DD4B39;
    font-size:smaller;
}
```

This will select every `<label>` element whose for attribute value **ends** with `"TextBox"`

```
label[for$="TextBox"]{
    color:#DD4B39;
    font-size:smaller;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this:

```
label[for$="TextBox"]
{
    ...
}
```

More info at [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/attribute_selector/attribute%24=value)